# Need a help in writing case statement for the below scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a table as below:

| ID | Salary | plan | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 20000 | A | NULL |
| 1001 | 300 | B | NULL |
| 1002 | 40000 | A | 2023-04-31 |
| 1002 | 250 | B | NULL |

My Requirement is, for an employee if
PLAN=A and [END DATE] <> NULL
Then Salary should pick from Plan B
PLAN=A and [END DATE]=NULL
Then Salary Should pick from Plan A

I have framed my query as below but its not work out.

```
select ID,[PLAN],[End Date],
case when [PLAN]='A'and [End Date]<> 'NULL'
then Cast(Null as Nvarchar(Max))
when PLAN='A'and [End Date]= '#####' then [Salary]
else [Salary]
END [Updated_Salary]
from Table
```

Comment: `[End Date]<> 'NULL'` --> `[End Date] is not  NULL`

Comment: tried that too Jens.. no luck

Comment: Can you post your expected output here? i.e. Are you expecting one row per ID, or 4 rows? Some further sample data that covers more scenarios may also help, e.g. what if there is only a record for Plan A and it has an end date - would that return null for salary, or not return a record at all? What if there are two records for Plan A with no end date, which of the two salaries should be returned? If these scenarios are not possible, then explain the limitations in the data.

Comment: `2023-04-31`? April only has 30 days. Is your date column *not* a `date`?

Comment: Do you store dates in a varchar column?!? Change to a proper data type, and this will become easier.

Comment: You could consider carrying out a pivot and extracting your values with a case expression.

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: GarethD,
There is a situation where we are maintaining 2 salary plans ie, PLAN A and PLAN B for some of the employees. 
-For a particular employee if the there is a [End Date] for PLAN A then we have to pick up salary from PLAN A.
-If there is no [End Date] then we have to pick up from PLAN A itself
-If there is no PLAN A and only exists PLAN B then the salary should be from PLAN A

Comment: I have tried below
select ID, [PLAN],[End Date],
 Case when [PLAN]='A' and [End Date] is not null
   then
   (case when [PLAN]='B'
   then [Salary] end
   )
  when [PLAN]='A'
  and [End Date] is null
  then [Salary]
Else [Salary] end [Updated_salary]

-Looks to me that after then clause I am not able to pick up PLAN B Data.

Answer (score 0):

```
with your_table(ID,Salary,plann,End_Date)
as
(
    select 1001,    20000,   'A',   NULL union all
    select 1001,    300, 'B',   NULL union all
    select 1002,    40000,   'A', '2023-04-30' union all
    select 1002,    250, 'B' ,  NULL
 )
 select x.id,
 case
   when x.plann='A' and X.End_Date is not null then X.b_salary
   when x.plann='A' and X.End_Date is null then X.Salary
 end as Flagg
from
(
  select a.id,a.Salary,a.plann,a.End_Date,
  b.ID as b_id,b.Salary as b_salary,b.plann as b_plann,b.End_Date as b_end_date
 from your_table as a
 left join your_table as b on a.ID=b.ID and a.plann<>b.plann 
)as x
```

Can not be sure about the requirements, but may be something like that can be a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not clear what is the expected results you wanted it to be. But I will try to fix your query to check whether the [End Date] is null or not by using this query below.

```
SELECT ID, [PLAN], [End Date],
    CASE WHEN [PLAN]='A'AND [End Date] <> NULL
        THEN null
    WHEN PLAN='A'AND [End Date] = NULL
        THEN [Salary]
    ELSE [Salary]
END [Updated_Salary]
FROM SAMPLE;
```

Comment: A value is never `= NULL` or `<> NULL` . It `IS NULL`or it `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

self join table based on ID and Plan type if Plan A type end date is not null consider the type of salary in A else consider B

```
declare  @table table(
ID int ,
Salary decimal(18,2),
planType varchar(2), 
EndDate dateTime
)

insert into @table
values (1001  ,  20000 ,  'A'  , NULL),
(1001   , 300 ,'B'   ,NULL),
(1002  ,  40000 ,  'A'  , 2023-04-31),
(1002   , 250,'B' ,  NULL)

select t1.ID,case when t1.EndDate is not null then t2.Salary else t1.Salary end as Salary 
from @table t1 join @table t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.planType='A' and t2.planType='B'
```

the Resulting will be

| Id | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 20000 |
| 1002 | 250 |